# make imported modules accessible for further imported modules

Tags: python, import, module

There is a main program importing a module with classes or something usefull that another submodule shall use too. For example:

main.py:

    `import datetime
    datetime.now()
    import mod`

mod.py:

    `datetime.today()`

When importing 'mod' module python gives an error that 'datetime' is not defined. `datetime.today()` cant be executed.

What should I do if I need to create a modular app in python instead of one-file apllication program? Should I always repeat my imports at the head of each module file ? Or can I make imported modules accessible from further imported modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I always repeat my imports at the head of each module file?

Yes.  Every module needs to import what it needs to use.

As two great minds noted in the comments, the actual loading of the module only takes place once.  Multiple imports will reuse the already-loaded module, so it won't have any significant performance impact.

Comment: its probably worth mentioning ... if a module is already in memory python wont reload it .... so theres not the overhead most people worry about when they ask this question

Comment: It's worth noting here that python keeps a cache of already imported modules in `sys.modules`.  Once a module is imported, it won't be imported _again_.

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Seriously... very nice.

Comment: Edited answer to add that :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. Will do all that jazz with loading modules every time.